# List encoding in the DOT calculus

Tags: scala, types, dependent-type, dotty, scala-3

I was reading [The Essence of Dependent Object Types](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/rompf/papers/amin-wf16.pdf) and found the following encoding of Lists:

[image]

Why would one write:

```
nil: sci.List ∧ {A = ⊥}
```

in particular, why do we give A type bottom? Shouldn't the type be polymorphic like in cons?

Comment: Isn't this pretty much the definition of a bottom. This is exactly same as we do in Scala as of now. The `Nil` is still a `List[Nothing]`

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh I admit my ignorance in the subject. You seem to speak of bottom as if there were several possible bottom. To me this looks like saying A is exactly the unique bottom type Nothing. But then, does this mean that all lists share the same nil value? And that there is no instance of this value?

Comment: Bottom type (in Scala's case `Nothing`) is a subtype of all other types, so it can be used as any other type (because you will find no value where things breaks as it is an empty type). So yes `Nil: List[A]` for any `A`: (`Nil: List[String]`, `Nil: List[Int]`, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Nothing` is a bottom type is Scala - it is a type, which has no members, so you can easily say that each of its members is a member of every other type without lying.

On its own `Nothing` (as a return type) is used to say that function never returns value, which usually means that it throws exception. If you have any container/wrapper/factory/however you call if of `Nothing`, it means that it cannot contain a version of wrapper/whatever that contains/produces value:

- `List[Nothing]` - is a List without any values,
- `Future[Nothing]` - is a Future which runs in loop or ends up with exception
- `Option[Nothing]` - is Option, that cannot contain a value

When it comes to `List` if you decide on using `Cons`+`Nil` as encoding, let's say you want to do it without any weird things:

```
sealed trait List[A]
case class Cons[A](a: head, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]
case class Nil[A]() extends List[A]
```

You cannot simply use object `Nil` which would have easier usage and pattern matching, because you have to define its type everywhere. So unfortunately you cannot have one `Nil`, but you need a separate `Nil` for every type.

```
Cons(1, Cons(2, Cons(3, Cons(4, Nil[Int]))))
```

But, it you made `List[A]` covariant then if `A` is subtype of `B` then `List[A]` would be subtype of `List[B]`.

```
sealed trait List[+A] // notice + before A
case class Cons[+A](a: head, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]
case class Nil[+A]() extends List[A]
```

then we could make use of `Nothing` being a subtype of every other type:

```
val nil = Nil[Nothing]
Cons(1, Cons(2, Cons(3, Cons(4, nil))))
Cons("a", Cons("b", Cons("c", Cons("d", nil))))
```

at this point for our own convenience (e.g. pattern matching) we could make `Nil` an object:

```
sealed trait List[+A]
case class Cons[+A](a: head, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
```

Thanks to that we need only one `Nil` instead of one for every type.

That is how it works in the current Scala (2) and it hasn't changed in Dotty. DOT calculus in your example shows how this translates to formalism: instead of `Nothing` you have ⊥, everything else is basically the same but with a different notation.